# Page not loading due to long javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my web page I'm using a javascript checking to see when an element loads. I'm forcing this element to load, but the script seems to not be working correctly.

Here is what I'm doing,

```
var exists = false;
while(!exists)
{
    setTimeout(function () { }, 100);
    if ($('#reject-grid').length) {
        var exists = true;
        $("#loading").fadeOut();
        $("#wrapper").removeClass("hidden");
    }
}
```

So I'm looping until an element exists and waiting 100 ms each iteration. Then I do some work to essentially stop my spinner, which controls the loading screen.

Comment: `setTimeout()` only fires once. Change it with `setInterval()` and wrap the actual function inside it.

Comment: setTimeout(function () { }, 100) will not wait, it will just schedule the (empty) function to execute in 100ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking to repeat this every 100ms, but what you're actually doing is creating a bunch of empty timeout handles and running this code over and over again.

You want something like:

```
function checkRejectGrid() {
  if ($('#reject-grid').length) {
    $("#loading").fadeOut();
    $("#wrapper").removeClass("hidden");
  } else {
    setTimeout(checkRejectGrid, 100);
  }
}

checkRejectGrid();
```

Comment: This seems pretty slick. To know I understand your answer the checkRejectGrid will continuously get called until we notice #reject-grid. Then we finish our logic and exit?

Comment: It's called one time, and if the `reject-grid` doesn't exist yet, then the 100ms timer is set to call it again one more time. So it's not recursive, and it's not continuous - it's just on a timer, then on a new timer, then on a new timer, until finally the grid is found and then it won't be on another timer.